# Conditional rendering on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
render() {
        const tableStyle = this.getTableStyle();
        const tableSettings = this.getTableSettings();

        return (
            <div style={tables}>

                <TablePosition
                    contextMenuOn={true}
                    step={this.props.step}
                    pdfData={this.props.pdfData}
                    tableSettings={tableSettings}
                    tableStyle={tableStyle}
                    fileName={this.state.fileName}
                    tableSize={this.getTableSize()}
                    tableOffset={this.state.tableOffset}
                    desiredWidth={700}
                    updateXOffset={x => this.updateXOffset(x)}
                    updateYOffset={y => this.updateYOffset(y)}
                    markTable={() => this.markTable()}
                    setOutputLabels={(row, col, val) => this.setOuputLabels(row, col, val)}
                />
            </div>
        );

        if (!this.props.isThirdStep) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div style={sideBySide}>
                        <PDFViewer
                            isThirdStep={this.props.isThirdStep}
                            paginationCallback={this.handlePageChange}
                            pdfData={this.state.pdfData}
                            desiredWidth={600}
                            selectedPage={this.props.savedPageNo}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            );     
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <ReferenceMenu />
                </div>
            );     
        }
    }
```

In my component's render, I try to render several components based on certain conditions.

So, basically, the `TablePoisition` always stays there, and the `PDFViewer` and `ReferenceMenu` renders conditionally.

However, what I see on both conditions is only the `TablePosition` component.

Is this not supposed to work?

Comment: probably because you only return `TablePosition`, the second return is never evaluated

Comment: Do we just have to put all components for each condition then?

Comment: what you're trying to do is the equivalent of `fn() {return 1;}` 1 will ALWAYS be returned

Comment: @AravindS, no, the return statements should contain `jsx` elements, the logic belongs in the method, as it is

Comment: @Derek So, shall I just put all relevant components (re-use) for each condition?

Comment: @Dawn17 are you expecting that each component display on each condition?

Comment: @Derek then he can write a condition statement using `!this.props.isThirdStep` using JSX , right?

Comment: @AravindS not without making the code illegible and hacky, again, logic belongs outside of the return

Comment: @AravindS It's okay to have some logic inside the `render`; but, don't put any code outside a simple ternary if-statement or `{varName}` inside the return itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained since you want to combine two components you should change your render logic. One component will be sit there always and the other one will be rendered conditionally. So, you need to render that last component with the sticky one in the same return. I would do something like this:

```
renderPDFViewer = () => (
    <div>
        <div style={sideBySide}>
            <PDFViewer
                isThirdStep={this.props.isThirdStep}
                paginationCallback={this.handlePageChange}
                pdfData={this.state.pdfData}
                desiredWidth={600}
                selectedPage={this.props.savedPageNo}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
);

render() {
        const tableStyle = this.getTableStyle();
        const tableSettings = this.getTableSettings();

        return (
            <div>
            <div style={tables}>

                <TablePosition
                    contextMenuOn={true}
                    step={this.props.step}
                    pdfData={this.props.pdfData}
                    tableSettings={tableSettings}
                    tableStyle={tableStyle}
                    fileName={this.state.fileName}
                    tableSize={this.getTableSize()}
                    tableOffset={this.state.tableOffset}
                    desiredWidth={700}
                    updateXOffset={x => this.updateXOffset(x)}
                    updateYOffset={y => this.updateYOffset(y)}
                    markTable={() => this.markTable()}
                    setOutputLabels={(row, col, val) => this.setOuputLabels(row, col, val)}
                />
                </div>

        {
            !this.props.isThirdStep
                ? this.renderPDFViewer()
                : ( <div><ReferenceMenu /></div> )
        }
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: How does `!this.props.isThirdStep` part work? It gives me an error `this.renderPDFView()` is not a function`

Comment: This is a perfect example of why logic belongs outside the return. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Though a downvote :) Nevermind. @Dawn17, this is an example of conditional rendering with ternary operators. It is a great way of rendering two things conditionally. If `this.props.isThirdStep` is false it invokes `this.renderPDFView()` function, otherwise it renders `ReferenceMenu` component. If it says there is not a function there might be some typo in your code.

Comment: It is my typo and fixed it. Code is yours, so do not copy paste it blindly, if there is an error look carefully. I just gave an example here.

Comment: By the way, how you setup your render logic is totally up to you. Some says "do this like that, others say no, do like this". Do it yourself and see if it suits you. Here is a quote from official documentation: **Just like in JavaScript, it is up to you to choose an appropriate style based on what you and your team consider more readable.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to place your conditional renders inside variables or something similar.

```
var conditionContent1 = null;
var conditionContent2 = null;

if(condition1){
    conditionContent1 = <div>conditional content 1</div>;
}

if(condition2){
    conditionContent2 = <div>conditional content 2</div>;
}

return (
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div>
            content
        </div>
        {conditionContent1}
        {conditionContent2}
    </div>
);
```

I added a wrapper `div`; because, I believe `render`'s `return` doesn't like having multiple root elements.

If the variables are null; then, it won't affect the overall render.

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it, aside from maybe extracting away the display into its own component to handle all the shared logic of the individual steps components

Comment: @Derek Possibly. It depends on the conditional content. Even if the content was abstracted into different components, the overall code here probably wouldn't change. It's just less JSX inside the if-statements.